# How do I crawl data that only appear after you click on a button?

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy

I'm trying to make a database of game statistics from League of Legends. I'm using https://op.gg as the source, and I can now crawl data that appears as default after searching a name, but I want data that only presents itself after clicking on something.

By default the html shows the following:

```
<div class="GameItem Lose" data-summoner-id="2919237" data-game-time="1557391914" data-game-id="3653488889" data-game-result="lose">
```

But after pressing a button, it will change to:

```
<div class="GameItem Lose extended" data-summoner-id="2919237" data-game-time="1557391914" data-game-id="3653488889" data-game-result="lose">
```

And the data I need are under the new sections.

I've tried going through the scrapy tutorial, using Docker, but that only seems to go so far as to explain how you can get pre-loaded data with javascript.

Comment: I would first advise you to read the [Terms of Service](https://euw.op.gg/about/agreement/) of OP.GG:
"You are further prohibited from (a) scraping or data mining while using the Sites or Services; (b) blocking, overwriting, modifying and copying of any contents of the Sites; or (c) performing any actions that may impair the operability of the Sites’ infrastructure, particularly actions that may overload said infrastructure, servers, bandwidth or other equipment or software" If you consider this as a general problem, I think there should be more willingness to answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the heads up. This is only one of many possible datasets that I want to build, so yes, it's a general problem that I only used this one as an example for. I will definitely check the Terms of Service from the sites I want to crawl from this point onwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the Selenium package!

I used it for a similair case as you. I had to scrape all the comments of a youtube video. They only appear when you scroll down and wait for them to load.
Check my [code](https://github.com/lubcountcooper/python-onsite/blob/master/week_04/web_scraping/05_bonus_task.py). Disclaimer: it's not well commented and structured, since it was an excercise for a course I did, but it gives you an idea.

Selenium simulates as if you are operating a browser. So you can see it scroll down the page, then wait for a while, and click things. I found it pretty cool!

Good luck and enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will check your code out as guidance!